# How to get the PORT number it is listening on?

Tags: meteor, environment-variables, port

I tried `process.env['PORT']`, but this returns an unrelated number.

I'm using Meteor 0.9.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're running your app using `meteor` command. When you do that, it will first start a proxy server which will listen on the port you give (by default 3000) and forward requests to your meteor application which listens on some random available port. Meteor does this to automatically refreshes the server when you modify a file and for some other cool features.

If you build your app using `meteor build --directory /my/build/path/` and run it, `process.env.PORT` will have the correct port number.

Comment: Sounds good reason ;-) So how can I detect that I'm running the dev version and not the bundled one?

Comment: It looks like you may be able to use Meteor.absoluteUrl(), but see https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-absoluteurl-does-not-include-the-port/35786